# Need to search a text file for a string and capture a second string located after the first

Tags: json, powershell

I'm working with an API call and I need to parse the JSON returned by the API in PowerShell. I'm searching for a particular name and then I need to capture a another item that follows it.

```js
$json = @"
{
    "Test": [
        {
            "association": "(None)",
            "description": "",
            "displayName": "BusIntel48.png",
            "galleryImage": "[PlugIn]Images;Trebuchet.PlugIn.Images.Images.Common.BusIntelligence.BusIntel48.png",
            "id": "944f73cc5c1a812eaa2ade43bd9ca0c9a40f963c56",
            "links": [],
            "localizedScopeName": "Built in",
            "name": "BusIntel48.png",
            "parentFolder": "ImagesCommonBusIntelligence",
            "parentIsScopeFolder": false,
            "scope": "FromResource",
            "scopeOwner": "",
            "standInKey": "DefType:ImageDef#Scope:FromResource#Id:944f73cc5c1a812eaa2ade43bd9ca0c9a40f963c56"
        },
        {
            "association": "(None)",
            "description": "",
            "displayName": "BusProcActOnEvent16.png",
            "galleryImage": "[PlugIn]Images;Trebuchet.PlugIn.Images.Images.Common.BusIntelligence.BusProcActOnEvent16.png",
            "id": "944f73cc5cb33339be6db84987baef3f7190c931cf",
            "links": [],
            "localizedScopeName": "Built in",
            "name": "BusProcActOnEvent16.png",
            "parentFolder": "ImagesCommonBusIntelligence",
            "parentIsScopeFolder": false,
            "scope": "FromResource",
            "scopeOwner": "",
            "standInKey": "DefType:ImageDef#Scope:FromResource#Id:944f73cc5cb33339be6db84987baef3f7190c931cf"
        }
    ]
}
"@

$x = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$name = $x.Test | where { $_.name -eq "BusIntel48.png" }
```

I need to search for the name of the image file (ex. "name": "BusIntel48.png") and then capture the string after "standInKey: (ex. DefType:ImageDef#Scope:FromResource#Id:944f73cc5c1a812eaa2ade43bd9ca0c9a40f963c56).

Comment: That looks like JSON, so you may want to use the built-in JSON parser rather than fiddling around with regular expression matches.

Comment: Good call, didn't even think of that. I'm looking more into the json file parsing now, and I've updated my original question with some of that code. Still not sure how to grab the stand in key though?

Comment: Append `| Select-Object -Expand standInKey`.

Comment: That is what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just need a change in last line.

You can also select one property by using :

```
$name = $x.Test | where { $_.name -eq "BusIntel48.png" } | Select-Object -Property "standInKey"
```